# How is (true != false != true) different from (false != true != false)?

Tags: java, boolean

I recently took an entry test in Java and this question confused me.
The full question is:

```
boolean b1 = true;
boolean b2 = false;
if (b2 != b1 != b2) 
    System.out.println("true");
else 
    System.out.println("false");
```

My first question is what (b2 != b1 != b2) means and the second question, as specified in the title, is how (false != true != false) evaluates to true while (true != false != true) evaluates to false (I tested that on Netbeans).

Comment: `b2 != b1 != b2` is *two* comparisions, 1) `b2 != b1`, followed by 2) `x != b2`, where `x` is the result of the first comparison.

Comment: [*"The equality operators are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right)."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21)

Comment: Btw, the answer for this in the real world is "just don't write that." :-) Java exams often seem to throw weird and hard-to-reason-about constructs at you, I guess either to show how clever the test writers are, or because they can't think of anything better. But precisely because this stuff is hard to read, in the real world you would just break it apart into a couple temporary variables with good names, and make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two boolean comparisons where the first comparison produces a result that is compared to another boolean value (the last one).
And the equality operators are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

To understand you can rewrite the actual comparison by doing the comparison in two times :

1) `false != true != false` == `true`  as

```
boolean result = false != true; // ->true
result = true != false; // ->true
result == true;
```

2) `true != false != true` == `false`  as

```
boolean result = true != false; // -> true
result = true != true; // -> false
result == false;
```

Or you can also enclose the fist comparison by parenthesis to ease the reading of the evaluations precedence (left to right) :

1)  `false != true != false` == `true`  as

```
 <=> (false != true) != false 
 <=>      true       != false
 <=>      true
```

2) `true != false != true` == `false`  as

```
 <=> (true != false) != true 
 <=>     true        != true
 <=>     false
```

Answer (score 0):

it will evaluate this way :

1-`false != true != false` = `false!=true`=`true`

so this `false != true` became `true` and then equation become like this

`true` != `false` which is equal to `true`

so the result is `true`.

Now for second one you can evaluate the same way as

2- `true != false != true`

`true!=false` which is `true`

now `true != true` which  is `false` so you are getting result as `false`

Answer (score 0):

See what happens most of the compiler start evaluating the expression from left to right 
So in this case what is happening first it is evaluating this.

`False != True == True //is evaluated first which is true`

Then it evaluates with this true we got from the first expression

```
True != False == True //which is also true
```

So the completer expression goes like this

```
False != True != False == True// which is True
```

Now in the second case the expression is like

```
True != False != True == False
```

the outputs for fist expression which is True != False evaluates for True and expression becomes True != True which is false

I hope it makes sense. It’s because the associativity of != is from left to right so it evaluating from left to right.